# Is it possible to dump the memory of a program to file and restore it again?

Tags: memory, core-dump

I want to create a copy the RAM used by a certain program to a file. And then restore that state again later.

Something similar to the effect of ctrl+z & fg, but I also want to free the RAM from that program.

Comment: For Linux, take a look at https://criu.org/ (I personally never got it working spotlessly)

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain if you want to restore the program state after a long time (including reboot) and what kind of programs and applications (HPC?) do you have in mind. Can you improve the code of that program?

Comment: use a lxc container to run your app and suspend the container when needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to create a copy the RAM used by a certain program to a file. And then restore that state again later.

Misconception: a [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and uses [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). The RAM itself is a resource managed by the OS kernel. Read [*Operating System: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) (a process does not use *directly* RAM).

<sup>(you'll better edit and improve your question a lot to explain much more about it: what kind of program do you have in mind, in what context, why, for how long do you need to "stop" the program, do you need to restart later an improved version of it...? without these details we cannot help much more.)</sup>

On Linux, you could use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to query the virtual address space of some given process.  Try `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps`

> I also want to free the RAM

No need for that, since the kernel is managing the RAM (sometimes [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_(computer_science)) could happen). See also [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html), [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html). When a process terminates, the kernel will release its virtual address space, and later reuses RAM allocated for it. When a process stops (e.g. thru <kbd>Ctrl Z</kbd> sending `SIGTSTP`, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)), the kernel might reuse its RAM for other purposes (and use swap space to store dirty pages -i.e. [page out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)- of that stopped process). Read about [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) & http://linuxatemyram.com/

What you want is related to **[application checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing)** and **orthogonal [persistence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science))**. On Unix and Linux (and most other OSes, including Windows, Android, MacOSX, ...) it is **not possible** or very difficult ***in general*** (how would you handle opened [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), [child processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process), [sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets), [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), [semaphores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), [threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), [file locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking), [graphical user interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface), [shared libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)#Shared_libraries), etc...). But you could write an application with such feature (and you can find libraries helping in that); of course you'll follow some additional conventions and restrictions to make persistence or checkpointing feasible and practical.

If you want that system-wide, consider [hibernation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)).

Persistence is something to be thought of very early at design time of your application (it may be difficult to add afterwards). Notice that [databases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) ([sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system), [nosql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases, ...) and indexed files ([gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/manual/gdbm.html) ...) can be viewed as a common way to achieve *some kind* of persistence (you could view your heap as a [cyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_graph) of objects). Persisting code-related data (e.g. [classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(computer_programming)), [vtables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table), [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), [function pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer) ...) is hard in general.

You can find some [libraries for checkpointing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing#Implementations_for_applications), e.g. [BLCR](http://crd.lbl.gov/departments/computer-science/CLaSS/research/BLCR/) or [CRIU](https://criu.org/). Of course they work in a limited context on applications developed to use them.

At last, from the algorithmic point of view, persisting the entire state (or checkpointing it) is very close to copying precise [garbage collectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)). So reading something about them, e.g. the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/), is useful.

However, genuine persistence or checkpointing is difficult to implement and should be though of early at design time of your application. In many cases, it is hard enough to **require a full rewrite of an application** not providing it.

Stay compatible with the evolution of the code is even harder (e.g. being able to restart with a newer version of your code applied to an old checkpoint). You might get inspired by [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating) techniques.

Some programming languages implementations (e.g. Ocaml, Python, Java, ...) provide [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) or [marshalling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) facilities that could help. Others have some way of checkpointing (e.g. SBCL [`save-lisp-and-die`](http://sbcl.org/manual/index.html#Saving-a-Core-Image), [PolyML](http://www.polyml.org) `export`). [Homoiconicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity) and [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) are helpful programming language features.

See also [RefPerSys](https://refpersys.org/) and [Bismon](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) as examples of persistent systems.

Comment: Thanks for the technical info. Would like to know more about the libs / syscalls which would help achieve that

Comment: It is not that easy. I added more references.

Comment: See also the [Process images](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=System_image&oldid=1018893446#Process_images) section of the "System image" page on Wikipedia -- this used to be a standard feature on some OSes at some point, and also in Smalltalk and Lisp Machines, but when it was found not to present on other OSes, programs like TeX and Emacs had to implement their own dump/undump at the application level.

Answer (score 4):

> Something similar to the effect of ctrl+z & fg, but I also want to free the RAM from that program.

Ctrl-z and `fg` will do exactly what you want: When the kernel needs RAM, it will write out the RAM the suspended program uses to disk into the swap partition, so it can re-use the RAM for something else. When the program is activated with `fg` later, it will read in that RAM from swap.

Comment: Won'tr work on the long term. You cannot persist a process and restart it after reboot that way.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The question said nothing about "it needs to persist after a reboot". The phrasing "but I also want to free the RAM" suggests that surviving reboots is probably not the intention in the first place, and the poster just didn't realize virtual memory will already take care of saving the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly of some interest, early versions of the document generation program TeX and LaTeX built their variants using tools which would start the base program, load all the various modules required, then trigger a core dump, and build a new "pre-configured" executable from the core dump.

There's some [good discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417624/installation-procedures-of-early-tex-installations?rq=1) over on tex.stackexchange.

I think even in the day it was considered an odd way to proceed, and it only really effected a form of run-time pre-linking, it didn't preserve the state of the running process (dynamic variable values, etc.) at all.

Apparently early versions of emacs did this also, I had not known that.

Comment: Current TeX (or emacs) has some persistence, but does not trigger a core dump for that

Comment: So a core dump only dumps the applications virtual memory, and does not affect other running processes

Answer (score 1):

Other than Ctrl+Z & fg it's not likely that you will be able to do what you want.

The problem is that while it's possible to save the memory of a process to a file (for example producing a core-dump) you seem to aim at being able to remove the process from the kernel's process table. But when doing that you will release all other OS resources hold by the process, for example open files etc.

Normally when creating those resources the method of their acquisition is not stored - which means that there is nowhere stored information on how to reacquisite the resources. Even if that information was saved somewhere there's no guarantee that reacqusite them later is possible anyway (the successful acquisition may depend on state external to the process or even computer which might have changed).